# Internet Explorer HTML5 video starts only after some time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing the problem that a video does not start to play, which I added to an HTML5 page:

```
<video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"
       muted="muted" volume="0" poster="http://test.com/poster.jpg">
     <source src="http://test.com/texas.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="http://test.com/texas.webm" type="video/webm">
     <img src="http://test.com/texas.jpg" />
</video>
```

- In Chrome and Firefox it works fine; the video starts in one second.
- In Internet Explorer I have to wait some time for video to start.
- In Safari it does not start at all.

How to fix it?

Comment: IE doesn't support video streaming so it has to load the whole video before playing.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, with MP4 files, the information regarding the length etc. of the file is at the end rather than the start of the file, so some browsers need to download the entire thing to get this information in order to play the file.

Try running [QTIndexSwapper 2](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/) on the file which will move the required information to the start of the file, if it needs to be.

It's worth a try.